# K8s cluster in peered VPC can't reach RDS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, networking

I have two K8s clusters in the same VPC that I want to connect to an MySQL
Aurora RDS cluster. One of the clusters can reach the RDS cluster just fine.
The other, however, cannot. I'll call these `eks-cluster-working` and
`eks-cluster-broken`.

I have a security group allowing traffic to the cluster:

| Type | Protocol | Port range | Source | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MYSQL/Aurora | TCP | `3306` | `sg-1` (eks-cluster-sg-working) | This rule works |
| MYSQL/Aurora | TCP | `3306` | `sg-2` (eks-cluster-sg-broken) | This one does not |

Both `eks-cluster-working` and `eks-cluster-broken` have the same default
security groups that AWS creates when making an EKS cluster and they are both
on the same K8s version (1.18). The one exception is that `eks-cluster-working`
has an extra security group for the load balancer service since it's hosting a
web service and the other one (`eks-cluster-broken`) is not. Both clusters
have outbound traffic rules that can reach `0.0.0.0/0`.

I have zero firewalls, firewall policies and network firewall rule groups set
up in the region the clusters are hosted in.

This is the Terraform configuration I have set up for peering from my VPCs
to the default VPC.

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "default_to_environment" {
  count       = local.num_environment_vpcs
  peer_vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.environment[count.index].id
  auto_accept = true
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_default_id

  tags = {
    Name      = "Peer from default to ${data.aws_vpc.environment[count.index].tags["Name"]}"
    tf_module = "vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "r" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_default_id

  # route = local.route_table_routes

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "igw-<number>"
  }

  dynamic route {
    for_each = [for r in local.route_table_routes : {
      cidr_block                = r.cidr_block
      vpc_peering_connection_id = r.vpc_peering_connection_id
    }]
    content {
      cidr_block                = route.value.cidr_block
      vpc_peering_connection_id = route.value.vpc_peering_connection_id
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "default to environment VPCs"
  }
}
```

### Expected result

I expect `eks-cluster-broken` to be able to connect to the RDS cluster just
like `eks-cluster-working` can.

### Question

What can cause this? Any suggestions as to how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my Peering Connection, I went to:

"Actions" -> "Edit DNS Settings" -> "Allow accepter VPC (`vpc-<id>`) to resolve DNS of requester VPC (vpc-`<id-default>`) hosts to private IP"

and checked it. (It was unchecked before). I had to wait a little while before this took effect.